# The performance tags are proliferating again. Can we synonymise and merge a few?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

These are my suggestions:

- [sqlperformance](/questions/tagged/sqlperformance), [sql-server-performance](/questions/tagged/sql-server-performance), [postgresql-performance](/questions/tagged/postgresql-performance), [sqlperformance](/questions/tagged/sqlperformance) and [query-performance](/questions/tagged/query-performance) into [database-performance](/questions/tagged/database-performance)
- [performance-counter](/questions/tagged/performance-counter) and [performancecounters](/questions/tagged/performancecounters) into [performance-counters](/questions/tagged/performance-counters)
- [performance-test](/questions/tagged/performance-test) and [web-performance-test](/questions/tagged/web-performance-test) into [performance-testing](/questions/tagged/performance-testing)
- [application-performance](/questions/tagged/application-performance) into [peformance](/questions/tagged/peformance)

The overall trend seems to have been [to synonymise](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/performance/synonyms) everything into [performance](/questions/tagged/performance). I don't really see the need for one for each language, as the other tags are meant to provide that information. So I would also synonymise and merge:

[android-performance](/questions/tagged/android-performance), [javascript-performance](/questions/tagged/javascript-performance), [jquery-performance](/questions/tagged/jquery-performance), [linq-performance](/questions/tagged/linq-performance), [wcf-performance](/questions/tagged/wcf-performance) and the database related ones into [performance](/questions/tagged/performance).

Then as [performance-tuning](/questions/tagged/performance-tuning) is already a synonym of [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) I would put the new  [performance-testing](/questions/tagged/performance-testing) into [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) as well.

I'm unsure about [performance-estimation](/questions/tagged/performance-estimation), [performance-monitoring](/questions/tagged/performance-monitoring) and [performance-measurement](/questions/tagged/performance-measurement). They could be useful separately.

Based on Robert Harvey's comments these need tag wiki's rather than synonymising to ensure they're not misused:

- [performancecounter](/questions/tagged/performancecounter)
- [queryperformancecounter](/questions/tagged/queryperformancecounter)

Comment: I opened this question with the intention of voting to close.  Well played =)

Comment: I capitalised jQuery correctly @jadarnel27... should have given you a clue :-).

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter is a [Windows function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `PerformanceCounter` is a .NET class in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Comment: Fair enough @Robert; I'm definitely not an expert. I've updated the question.

Comment: Performance Monitor is a Windows tool.

Comment: I feel like [tag:performance] shouldn't exist. It's too ambiguous. I feel like we should have: [tag:performance-testing], [tag:performance-optimization], and [tag:performance-counters]. [tag:database-performance] has no merit. Instead one could use [tag:sql] [tag:performance-optimization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I made most of the changes, and fixed up the tag wikis for the Windows-specific tags.  I didn't merge anything, in case we want to change or reverse some of these later.

Comment: That was quick, thanks!